# opshub v2.2.2 not considering test case work items

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

In our organization, we are migrating TFS 2010 team projects into VSO. we use opshub v 2.2.2 to migrate our team projects. After configuring new migration process, opshub considers all the work item types and migrate them smoothly except test cases. It is not considering any revisions from test cases to process. please see below snapshot. What I miss here?

[image]

Comment: I can get the same behavior as you.

Answer (score 0):

Test Case and Shared Steps are a part of Test Entities Suite. The free version of the OVSMU does not support Test Entities migration.